# Cypress.moment using locale

Tags: automated-tests, locale, cypress

I am trying to use Cypress.moment to compare dates. The targeted website is in french so the date format.

Therefore, I intended to use moment.js method to switch fr locale.

```
Cypress.moment.locale('fr')
```

I should be able to do that as they say on cypress documentation :

> Cypress automatically includes moment.js and exposes it as Cypress.moment
>   https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/moment.html#Syntax

Then,

```
const todaysDate = Cypress.moment().format('Do')
const currentMonth = Cypress.moment().format('MMMM')

cy.get('.date__title').should('contain', todaysDate)
cy.get('.c-title').should('contain', currentMonth)
```

But the assertion fails as cypress refuse to take into account the fr locale. It keeps comparing 'décembre' with 'december' for instance. Which fails obviously.

I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the [same aforementioned thread](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2963), a working answer recently surfaced:

put this in `support/index.js`:

```js
Cypress.moment.locale('de');
```

it worked brilliantly in my project

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at the time of writing, I think this is not possible with `Cypress.moment.locale()`, as you can see in [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2963) issue in their git repository.

As commented there `moment.locale` requires an import in addition to the standard `moment` import, that import is `moment-with-locales.min.js` and has not been included in Cypress.